# how to reference a bean of another xml file in spring

Tags: java, spring, reference, javabeans

I have a Spring bean defined in an xml file. I want to reference it from another xml file. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

### Import

```
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/that-other-xml-conf.xml"/>

<bean id="yourCoolBean" class="org.jdong.MyCoolBean">
    <property name="anotherBean" ref="thatOtherBean"/>
</bean>
```

### Include in the `ApplicationContext` Construction

Make both files a part of your `ApplicationContext` when you create it => then no import is needed.

For example if you need it during testing:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/this-xml-conf.xml",
                    "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/that-other-xml-conf.xml" })
public class CleverMoneyMakingBusinessServiceIntegrationTest {...}
```

In case it is a web app, you'd do it in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/conf/spring/this-xml-conf.xml</param-value>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/conf/spring/that-other-xml-conf.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If it is a stand alone app, library, etc.. you would load your `ApplicationContext` as:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( 
    new String[] { "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/this-xml-conf.xml",
                   "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/that-other-xml-conf.xml" } );
```

Comment: syntax issue? @ContextConfiguration(locations={"base-context.xml"})

Comment: for me `web.xml` chunk throws error. One `param-value` seems to be allowed only in place.

Comment: For import: Can't we access beans in another xml file using `ref` without using `<import>` if the xml is defined in the same application? [Ref](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-reference-example/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20referring%20to,tag%2C%20'%20bean%20'%20attribute.&text=In%20this%20example%2C%20the%20bean,beans%20in%20'%20Spring%2DOutput.)

Answer (score 7):

Just import the xml defining the bean with  `<import resource="otherXml.xml">` and you will be able to use the bean definition.

You can use `classpath:` in the `resource` attribute:

```
<import resource="classpath:anotherXXML.xml" />
```

See the "3.18. Importing Bean Definitions from One File Into Another" in [this chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html) of the Spring Reference

Comment: I did that, but after refresh, system fell into a infinite status. did i do anything wrong?

Comment: Didn't spring trace any exception, or information on what it was doing in that infinite status? Also, take a look at @JBNizet 's suggestion, this would be only necessary if those xml's are not part of the same application context. See the "3.2.2.1. Composing XML-based configuration metadata" section in [this chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) of the 2.5 reference (the link I gave in my answer may be of a somewhat outdated spring version).

Answer (score 5):

You reference it exactly as you would reference a bean in the same XML file. If a spring context is composed of several XML files, all the beans are part of the same context, and thus share a unique namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you are just refactoring beans into several files to keep the single xml file from growing to large, simply reference it from its current folder:

```
<import resource="processors/processor-beans.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also go about this by loading multiple Spring bean configuration files in the code :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    new String[] {"Spring-Common.xml", "Spring-Connection.xml","Spring-ModuleA.xml"});
```

Put all spring xml files under project classpath:

```
project-classpath/Spring-Common.xml
project-classpath/Spring-Connection.xml
project-classpath/Spring-ModuleA.xml
```

However, the above implementation is a lack of organizing and error prone, the better way should be organized all your Spring bean configuration files into a single XML file. For example, create a `Spring-All-Module.xml` file, and import the entire Spring bean files like this :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="common/Spring-Common.xml"/>
    <import resource="connection/Spring-Connection.xml"/>
    <import resource="moduleA/Spring-ModuleA.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Now you can load a single xml file like this :

```
ApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(Spring-All-Module.xml);
```

Note
In Spring3, the alternative solution is using [JavaConfig @Import](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-import-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [tolitius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7714450/12133207) is very detailed.
Just for the problem mentioned by [Peter Butkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1581069/peter-butkovic)

> for me web.xml chunk throws error. One param-value seems to be allowed only in place. – Peter Butkovic

I met the same problem and solved by spliting two paths with "," in the same  tag.

It will look like this

```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
                     /WEB-INF/daoContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```