# Configuration error: Not able to redirect to my home.jsp page

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I'm facing this problem but i have given appservlet in my servlet-context.xml but i m wondering from where it is taking the uri[hibernate] how can i redirect to my home.jsp page

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

My Servlet-Context.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring"></context:component-scan>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
     <beans:bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="test" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="encore123" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.xml"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDao" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:import resource="classpath:src/test/resources/hibernate.xml" />
```

My Hibernate.xml

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>       
      <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    <mapping resource="net/codejava/spring/model/User.hbm.xml"/>
   </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

My pom.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.1.2</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
       <name>SpringHibernateInteg</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
       <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                         <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
     </build>
    </project>
```

My controller

```
      package com.spring.hibernate;

   import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Locale;

   import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
    import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
     import org.springframework.ui.Model;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
     import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    /**
    * Handles requests for the application home page.
     */
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

   @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
    List<User> listUsers = userDao.list();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    model.addObject("userList", listUsers);
    return model;
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your `ServletContext.xhtml` I can see

```
 <beans:import resource="classpath:src/test/resources/hibernate.xml" />
```

However, `src/test/resources` is part of the classpath, and only when you're running `maven` tests.

When you're running your application, the classpath consists of

- `src/main/java`
- `src/main/resources`

In your case, the ClassLoader will try to resolve the file `src/test/resources/hibernate.xml` *on the classpath*, meaning that will be searched for the file `src/main/resources/src/test/resources/hibernate.xml` - and this clearly doesn't exist

Try to put `hibernate.xml` in `src/main/resources`, then change the configuration to

```
 <beans:import resource="classpath:hibernate.xml" />
```

and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711750/how-to-reference-a-bean-of-another-xml-file-in-spring) for further reading.

Comment: I have solved all the issues but i could not able to direct to my controller page even though i have configured all the files perfectly i am facing WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' i have not given /hibernate in my controller but i m wondering from where it is taking the uri can any one help me with this