# Referring bean declared in another xml file

Tags: xml, spring

I am writing a simple spring program with the following files.

BeanRef.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="refbean" class="com.springstarter.RefBean">
       <property name="anotherBean" >
       <ref bean="anotherbean"/>
       </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

AnotherXml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="anotherbean" class="com.springstarter.AnotherBean">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

RefBean.java

```
public class RefBean
{
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    public AnotherBean getAnotherBean()
    {
        return anotherBean;
    }

    public void setAnotherBean( AnotherBean anotherBean )
    {
        this.anotherBean = anotherBean;
    }
}
```

AnotherBean.java

```
public class AnotherBean
{
    private String message;

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage( String message )
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Main Program

```
public class BeanRefApp
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        @SuppressWarnings( "resource" )
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeanRef.xml");
        RefBean starter = ( RefBean ) context.getBean( "refbean" );
        System.out.println(starter.getAnotherBean().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Package structure:

[image]

As you can see in BeanRef.xml i'm trying to reference anotherbean declared in AnotherXml.xml.On run, it throws this exception,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'anotherbean' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
```

I think some inclusion code need to be added to BeanRef.xml to reference AnotherXml.xml. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BeanRef.xml`, import the other xml within `beans` tag like:

```
<import resource="classpath:AnotherXml.xml"/><!-- Assuming AnotherXml.xml is in your classpath as well-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this

```
<import resource="classpath:config/spring/that-other-xml-conf.xml"/>
    <bean id="yourCoolBean" class="org.jdong.MyCoolBean">
        <property name="anotherBean" ref="thatOtherBean"/>
    </bean>
```

Please find reference link for same :
[how to reference a bean of another xml file in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711750/how-to-reference-a-bean-of-another-xml-file-in-spring)